# xpath with multiple components

Tags: android, xpath

I'm trying to find an element that contain multiple ones with xpath for example

```
<ListView>
  <RelativeLayout>
    <TextView id=text1></TextView>
    <TextView id=text2></TextView>
    <ImageView id=img1></ImageView>
  </RelativeLayout>
  <RelativeLayout>
    <TextView id=text3></TextView>
    <TextView id=text4></TextView>
    <ImageView id=img2></ImageView>
  </RelativeLayout>
</ListView>
```

I would like to retrieve only the relative layout that contains a textview with id=text1, a textview with id=text2 and an imageview with id=img1

I tried this

```
//ListView/RelativeLayout/TextView[@resource-id='text1'] | 
//ListView/RelativeLayout/TextView[@resource-id='text2'] | 
//ListView/RelativeLayout/ImageView[@resource-id='img1']
```

And this

```
//ListView/RelativeLayout/TextView[@resource-id='text1'] and 
//ListView/RelativeLayout/TextView[@resource-id='text2'] and 
//ListView/RelativeLayout/ImageView[@resource-id='img1']
```

But none works.

The first one seems to be a select all that contain the 1st OR the 2nd OR the 3rd so not one with the 3 at the same time.

The second one doesn't select aything.

I suppose I should do something like

```
//ListView/RelativeLayout/TextView[@resource-id='text1'] and TextView[@resource-id='text2'] and ImageView[@resource-id='img1']
```

But I don't know how to properly write it :/

Any help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"I would like to retrieve only the relative layout that contains a textview with id=text1, a textview with id=text2 and an imageview with id=img1"*

You can do this way (wrapped for readability) :

```
//ListView/RelativeLayout[
            TextView/@resource-id='text1' and 
            TextView/@resource-id='text2' and 
            ImageView/@resource-id='img1'
          ]
```

or alternatively, something closer to your last attempted XPath :

```
//ListView/RelativeLayout[
            TextView[@resource-id='text1'] and 
            TextView[@resource-id='text2'] and 
            ImageView[@resource-id='img1']
          ]
```

Notice that the last element in the main path is the element that would be returned by the XPath, in this case it should be `/RelativeLayout`, as requested. Also notice that predicate expression (`[...]`) applied to  context node to the left, so the outer predicate in the two XPath above applied to `RelativeLayout` since the form is `/RelativeLayout[....]`.